# Running a python package from terminal

Tags: python, command-line, package

I have a python package like this:

```
package/
   setup.py 
   deb/
   build/
   sound/
     __init__.py
     run.py
     config.py
     readaudio.py
```

inside run.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python   

start():
    ...do something
resume():
    ....do something
if __name__=="__main__":
   start()
```

I have built a package and installed it, now I want to run the installed package from command line. Something like

```
$ ./sound.run
```

or

```
$ python sound.run.resume
```

I want to be able to do this system-wide ( or in a virtualenv), since that's the point of installing it. I know the commands above wouldn't work, but I hope this conveys the idea. I want to call the program not the functions within the python env.

But I am not sure how I can run it from command line **without** using something like this:

```
$ python -c " from sound import run; run.start();"
```

Any suggestions, is that even possible?

Comment: `python -m sound.run` (or mark it as a script in setup.py so it will get installed somewhere in your $PATH.)

Comment: how do I mark it as a script? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `setuptools`'s entry points feature to create a console script for your project

```
setup(name=project_name,
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['ez_setup', 'examples', 'tests']),
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    entry_points="""
    [console_scripts]
    sound-run = sound.run:start
    sound-resume = sound.run:resume
    """
    # Other setuptools stuff
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way I can specify where the entry point binaries are installed (sound-run,sound-resume)? currently they end up in /usr/local/bin/ but I would like to change that.

Comment: @carefullynamed, that depends which Python interpreter or virtualenv you're installing into. If you install into a virtualenv at `~/mytools`, it goes into `~/mytools/bin`, f/e. In general, `/usr/local/bin` is the Right Thing for globally-installed content in a conventional distro that isn't handled by the distro's native package manager; it'll be fewer surprises for other people if you don't change it.